# Identifying an XPath for a Tag which an attribute has span and div in it

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Can any one please help me to identify the XPath for this:

```
<a class="channel_code" href="javascript:void(0)" oldtitle="<span style="text-decoration: underline; margin: 4px">CID:</span><div style="margin: 8px 4px 4px;">channel unspecified as to episode of care</div>">1070.20</a>
```

Here i need to get the text 'channel episode of care' and validate it. The text that I am trying to get is actually a tooltip.

I am using xpath from past 1 year, but I have never come across such a different tag. Here the anchor tag it self is having multiple tags in it.

Comment: What kind of evil application produces HTML like that?

Answer (score 1):

The idea here would be to:

- locate the `a` tag
- get the `oldtitle` attribute value
- parse it with an HTML parser and get the text of the `div` element

Example using `Python` + `Selenium` + [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("my url here")

a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.channel_code")
oldtitle = a.get_attribute("oldtitle")

soup = BeautifulSoup(oldtitle)
print(soup.div.get_text())
```